# Collision not getting detected in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collision-detection

I am making a 2D game. I have 2 game objects, a player, and some obstacles and I want the player object to be destroyed on collision. I have added box colliders to both the objects as well as tags but the collision is not taking place as there are no log messages in the console.

[image]

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col)
{
    Debug.Log("collision name = " + col.gameObject.name);
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "cow") {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that at least one object has attached a `Rigidbody2D`

Comment: @PawełMarecki Thanks a lot ! This was the problem.Game works after adding 'Rigidbody2D'.

Comment: Great :) I've added an answer to clean the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed in comments:

Add `Rigidbody2D` component to at least one of colliding objects.